# clear command in console dialog

Tags: shell-script, dialog

My bash script contains the `clear` command, that when executed through `dialog` command will result with strange letters.
How can I still use `clear` command without seeing this output in the dialog?

This is an example of how to produce this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting..."
clear
echo ""
echo "End"
```

I'm using the `dialog` sort of like this:

```
bash /tmp/1.sh | dialog --progressbox 30 80
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could redirect the output of [`clear`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/clear.1.html) to the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting..."
clear >$(tty)
echo ""
echo "End"
```

`clear` writes to its standard output, which (when redirected in this manner) can be different from the script's standard output.

Comment: its almost works for me because from some reason if you have 'sleep' command also between echo's command the dialog completely distorted. just add 'sleep 1' between echo command and see in order to simulate it.

Comment: `sleep` is a different problem: writing through a pipe, the data is not line-buffered, and the `sleep` acts to make that apparent.